# Ошибка: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript

На сайте появляется ошибка:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$('.entry-content').offset().top')

Вот код

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
console.log("Start");
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    var dh;
    var faded = false;
    dh = $('.entry-content').offset().top;
    if ($(window).width() > 1000 && $('body').hasClass('single'))
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (offset > 270 && faded != true) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.adslot_1 center').fadeOut(400, function() {
                        $('.adslot_1 center').css({
                            'position': 'static'
                        }).fadeIn();
                    });
                }, 300)
                faded = true;
                return;
            }
        })
```

Класс `.entry-content` присутствует только на странице новости, на главной его нет. Видимо по этому и возникает ошибка. 
Данный скрипт открепляет прилепающую рекламу при скроле.
Как можно устранить эти проблему, чтобы на главной странице не выдавалась это ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки в том, что если на странице нет элемента с классом .entry-content, то `$('.entry-content').offset()` будет `undefined` и получится `dh = undefined.top;` А `undefined` - это не объект и у него нет свойства `top` это и написано в теле ошибки.

Поменяй

```
dh = $('.entry-content').offset().top;
```

На

```
dh = $('.entry-content').offset() && $('.entry-content').offset().top;
```

Comment: `$('.entry-content')` **никогда** не будет undefined

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я подкорректирую свой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое. помогло